# Alembic trying to delete my tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

Alembic beginner here. I'm having some issues with Alembic trying to delete my tables that are already created. I have no idea what is going on. Right now I have a database that looks like this:

[image]

If I run `alembic upgrade head`, I get this as my result:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
```

If I run `alembic history`, I get this result, which is correct:

```
c2659db918a9 -> 765c30f7078c (head), creat table views
c4a0cac54f89 -> c2659db918a9, Made last_update not null for all tables
19dd9f3d1d16 -> c4a0cac54f89, Added last_update field defaulted to now
77c03ebb393b -> 19dd9f3d1d16, Added indexes to each table
0737825277d8 -> 77c03ebb393b, Change foreign key columns to non-nullable
5eb3c5f7f599 -> 0737825277d8, Rename a column in daily_etf_underlying table
0da0b2a43172 -> 5eb3c5f7f599, Add extra_info column to daily_etf_underlying
c181fe8bcfa9 -> 0da0b2a43172, Make daily_etf id columns nullable
8fba2675104b -> c181fe8bcfa9, added fixing table
074563d69c3b -> 8fba2675104b, Modify daily_etf tables
2c9de57e43f0 -> 074563d69c3b, Add fund_family columns
80de6fb0a104 -> 2c9de57e43f0, Modify daily_etf table
a970af9bb117 -> 80de6fb0a104, Add daily_etf_basket, daily_etf_fx_forward tables
<base> -> a970af9bb117, Add daily_etf table
```

But if I run `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "<>"`, I get this!

```
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Raw fidessa client trade table"
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.ddl.postgresql] Detected sequence named 'daily_etf_fx_forward_id_seq' as owned by integer column 'daily_etf_fx_forward(id)', assuming SERIAL and omitting
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed table 'daily_etf_fx_forward'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed table 'daily_etf'
INFO  [alembic.ddl.postgresql] Detected sequence named 'daily_fx_fixing_rate_id_seq' as owned by integer column 'daily_fx_fixing_rate(id)', assuming SERIAL and omitting
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed table 'daily_fx_fixing_rate'
INFO  [alembic.ddl.postgresql] Detected sequence named 'daily_etf_underlying_id_seq' as owned by integer column 'daily_etf_underlying(id)', assuming SERIAL and omitting
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed table 'daily_etf_underlying'
Generating C:\dev\Projects\stark_database\stark_database\migrations\versions\86174c06e59e_raw_fidessa_client_trade_table.py ... done
```

And my autogenerated file is just trying to remove all my tables :(

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_table('daily_fx_fixing_rate')
    op.drop_table('daily_etf_underlying')
    op.drop_table('daily_etf')
    op.drop_table('daily_etf_fx_forward')
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

What is going on here? Why is alembic trying to delete everything?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: `alembic.ini`:

```
[alembic]
script_location = migrations
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://stark_admin:hpt@localhost/stark
```

`env.py` is exactly textbook to `alembic init alembic`

Comment: How's your table metadata and alembic configuration?

Comment: See edit. Thanks Ilja

Comment: Just to be sure, have you replaced `target_metadata = None` in env.py to point to your table metadata?

Answer (score 29):

I figured out. The `metadata` object was incorrect.

For those reading,

Make sure you have the correct `metadata` in `target_metadata = metadata`. If you have some tables already in the database and you supply a new `metadata` or a `None` metadata as Ilja suggested in the comments, you will see this behavior because alembic knows that based on that metadata, those tables should not be in the database, so it will try to delete those.

Moreover, typically you will have classes in different files for `SQLAlchemy`. For this to work, you have to make sure that you are using the same `metadata` or `Base` instance across the files. Otherwise, you will get this behavior of not detecting tables or trying to delete existing tables.

Here's an example of the latter situation:

Suppose I have a structure like

```
database
    /migrations
        /versions
            1348ht31r3_first_migration.py
        env.py
        README
        script.py.mako
    /models
        __init__.py
        a_class.py
```

In `__init__.py`, I do the typical `declarative_base()`:

```
# __init__.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('url')
```

And then in `a_class.py`, I have my model class whose parent class is the Base from `__init__.py`

```
from datetime import datetime

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float
from sqlalchemy import Date, DateTime
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from stark_database.models import Base


class AClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a_class'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    insert_date = Column(Date)
    symbol = Column(String)
    pnu = Column(Float)
    projected_shares_outstanding = Column(Float)
    shares_outstanding = Column(Float)
    projected_nav = Column(Float)
    nav = Column(Float)
    basket_cash_per_currency = Column(JSONB)
    fund_cash_per_currency = Column(JSONB)
    info_type = Column(String)
    fund_family = Column(String)
    last_updated = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)
```

This is correct, but in `env.py`, you have to make sure you import the Base class *and* the model.

```
from __future__ import with_statement

import os
import sys
from logging.config import fileConfig

from alembic import context
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config, pool

# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE. 
from database.models import Base, a_class
```

This isn't an `alembic` thing but it's a bit of a python gotcha in my opinion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The relevant documentation on the subject: http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/autogenerate.html

Comment: The alembic documentation at this link is unclear about what and does not describe these cases.

Comment: Having the same issue now that I separated my models.py into /models/model1.py, /models/model2.py etc system. We have 25+ models and growing. Do we constantly need to update env.py? Isn't there a better way?

Comment: just a wee additional point, you can just 'import database.models' without having to enumerate all the models. This means you don't have to edit the env.py every time you add a model (assuming all your SQLAlchemy models live in one file.

Answer (score 0):

Despite this being 6 years ago, I just ran into this myself.
I have a models.py with all my models, and in the env.py configuration for target_metadata, I noticed that this variable wasn't being used by the function get_metadata defined just below the declaration, so I returned it from that function and everything is working.

```html
# for 'autogenerate' support
from models import Base
target_metadata = Base.metadata
config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', get_engine_url())
target_db = current_app.extensions['migrate'].db

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.

def get_metadata():
    return target_metadata # ADD THIS LINE 
    if hasattr(target_db, 'metadatas'):
        return target_db.metadatas[None]
    return target_db.metadata
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem. I have several files with models in different subpackages and a `declarative_base` in a separate file.

```
├── alembic
│   ├── README
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── env.py
│   ├── script.py.mako
│   └── versions
├── alembic.ini
└── app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── subpackage1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── database.py
    └── subpackage2
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── models
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── model1.py
        │   ├── model2.py
        │   └── model3.py
        └── session.py  # the declarative_base is created here
```

The problem is when we try to import metadata in `env.py` (`from app.subpackage2.session import Base`) the code of the modules with models does not execute, models are not defined and thus metadata does not know about them existing. As was pointed out in the previous answers, we need to import all our models to `env.py` (we do not need modules itself, we just need a code execution).

To avoid collecting imports in `env.py`, you can gather all model imports in `__init__.py` of each package. For example `subpackage2/models/__init__.py` will look like this:

```
import app.subpackage2.models.model1
import app.subpackage2.models.model2
import app.subpackage2.models.model3
```

Then you can create a function that dynamically imports all models before returning the `Base` object and use it in `env.py`

```
# subpackage2/session.py

Base = declarative_base()

def get_base():
    import app.subpackage1
    import app.subpackage2.models
    return Base
```

And `alembic/env.py` will contain just this code:

```
from app.subpackage2.session import get_base

target_metadata = get_base().metadata
```

In this configuration we do not need to worry about adding new imports into `env.py`