# How to ensure a proper metadata object with Flask-SQLAlchemy to avoid Alembic deleting tables

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a Flask application where the database object creation and managment is handled using `Flask-SQLAlchemy` and the database migrations are done using `Flask-Migrate`

When I try to create a database migration using `flask db migrate` some of my tables are deleted in the resulting migration, similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695008/alembic-trying-to-delete-my-tables)

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed table 'media'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed table 'api'
```

In my virtualenv I have the `FLASK_APP` variable pointed to the class that contains the `create_app` factory and others.

```
declare -x FLASK_APP="app/app.py"
```

In `app/extensions.py` I have the `db` object defined as `db = SQLAlchemy()` and in `app/app.py` is where I have the create_app factory, configure the extensions and blueprints, etc.

```
from app.extensions import db

def configure_extensions(app):
  # Database
  db.init_app(app)

  # Flask-Migrate
  migrate.init_app(app, db)

def create_app():
    app = Flask("app")
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    configure_app(app, Config)
    register_blueprints(app)
    configure_extensions(app)

    return app
```

In my models. I have the model class defined as `db.Model` and not my own Base class, is this an issue?

```
from app.extensions import db, passlib
from app.database import CRUDMixin

class Media(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'media'
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        title = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
        # [sic]
```

How should I go about solving this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the model class `Media`/the module containing it imported at any point when creating migrations? If not, then there's your problem. In order for the tables to exist in the metadata, the model classes have to be evaluated/constructed. If the tables are missing from the metadata, alembic considers them removed and creates the migration accordingly.

Comment: You are right. That was the issue.